# How to cross-compile for iPhone with nix?

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-compiling, nix

I've been attempting to get cross-compilation to an iOS target working via nix. My tenative expression starts out like this:

```
{iphone ? false}:

let
  crossSystem = if iphone then {
    config = "aarch64-apple-ios";
    sdkVer = "13.7";
    xcodeVer = "11";
    xcodePlatform = "iPhoneOS";
    useiOSPrebuilt = true;
    platform = {};
  } else null;

  pkgs_fn = (import ../repo.nix).nixos_2009;
  cmake = (pkgs_fn {}).cmake;
  pkgs = pkgs_fn { config.allowUnfree = true; crossSystem = crossSystem; };
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  nativeBuildInputs = [
    cmake
  ];
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.zlib
    # ...
  ];
}
```

The problem I run into is that the [current xcode package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/os-specific/darwin/xcode/default.nix) does not have hashes that seem to correspond to any version I can download on Apple's website. In addition, the versions it nominally supports are extremely old (only the 10.x series and 11).

What's the idiomatic way to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Obsidian Systems is compiling for iOS with their [reflex-platform](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform). Perhaps they know more?

Comment: You can probably manually override the hashes to the ones you have observed. Would that work for you?